# How to use pnpm instead of npm in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, pnpm

I want t use `pnpm` instead of `npm` in my Github Actions, so I replace `npm` by `pnpm` in the file below:
`.github/workflows/build.yml`:

```
name: Generate a build and push to another branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Push

    steps:
      - name: git-checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install all dependencies
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Build
        run: pnpm run build # The build command of your project

      - name: Push
        uses: s0/git-publish-subdir-action@develop
        env:
          REPO: self
          BRANCH: build # The branch name where you want to push the assets
          FOLDER: dist # The directory where your assets are generated
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # GitHub will automatically add this - you don't need to bother getting a token
          MESSAGE: "Build: ({sha}) {msg}" # The commit message
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Run pnpm install
/home/runner/work/_temp/bac64766-f49a-4c8a-840d-dcccab703179.sh: line 1: pnpm: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

How should I modify my file to be able to use `pnpm` instead of `npm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm is installed on [runners by default](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#package-management), pnpm is not, this is why your workflow is failing.

To get pnpm installed on the runner, use https://github.com/pnpm/action-setup.

e.g.

```yaml
name: Generate a build and push to another branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Push

    steps:
      - name: git-checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: pnpm-setup
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
...
```